# passing information on Threaded TcpServer from one thread to another

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, tcp, server

I tried to create simple server like in link 1.
[Youtube tutorial to create multithreaded server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKtCXUHsV70)

```
void Test_Server::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor_)
{
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor_ << "connecting...";
    Test_Thread *thread_ = new Test_Thread(number_,socketDescriptor_,this);
    connect(thread_,SIGNAL(finished()),thread_,SLOT(deleteLater()));
    thread_->start();
    number_++;
}
```

////

```
void Test_Thread::run()
{
    qDebug() << this->Socket_Descriptor_ << "starting thread";
    socket = new QTcpSocket();
    if(!socket->setSocketDescriptor(Socket_Descriptor_))
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR";
    }
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(Ready_read_()),Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(disconnected_()),Qt::DirectConnection);
    qDebug() << this->Socket_Descriptor_ << "Client connected";
    QByteArray name = QByteArray::number(number_);
    server_->Socket_map_.insert(name,this);
    server_->show_all_connected_sockets_();
    exec();
}
```

My goal is to connect two clients to server(i use telnet), write from Client 1 to server something, and server should pass data to Client 2.
To do that I've made QMap to storage pointers to MyThreads. When data is received from Client 1, I'm calling method:

```
void Test_Server::write_to_client_(int number, QByteArray data)
{
QByteArray name = QByteArray::number(number);
    Test_Thread *pointer;
    pointer = client_socket_(name);
    connect(this,SIGNAL(send_data_(QByteArray)),pointer,SLOT(write_data_(QByteArray)));
    emit send_data_(data);
    disconnect(this,SIGNAL(send_data_(QByteArray)),pointer,SLOT(write_data_(QByteArray)));
    qDebug() << "void Test_Server::write_to_client_(int number, QByteArray data): data sent";
}
```

////

```
void Test_Thread::write_data_(QByteArray data) const
{
    socket->write(data);
    socket->waitForBytesWritten();
}
```

Generally passing information works, I write in Client 1 some data, and Client 2 shows it, however I'm geting:

> TQObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different
> thread.
>
> Parent Test_Thread is QNativeSocketEngine(Pointer 1), parent's thread is >(Pointer 2), current thread is (Pointer 3);
>
> QsocketNotifier: Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread.

My question is: how to correctly pass data from client 1, to server, and then to client 2? I've done reasearch and problem lies in proper use of Signals and Slots but I cannot find out how to do it in proper way.

Comment: I'm not sure the relevant part of the code (the one that makes the error) is in the code you posted.

Comment: @perencia in 'Test_Server::write_to_client_(int number, QByteArray data)' there was plenty of qDebug() lanes with info, I received errors after emiting a signal. write_data_ SLOT is implemented with 2 lane code, socket->write(data); and socket->waitforBytesWritten();

Comment: I'd say the problem is that the socket is created in the main thread and you are trying to use its QSocketNotifier on the second thread, which has a different event loop. How do `socket` arrives to Test_Thread ? Are you passing it from main thread ?

Comment: @perencia in _Server::incomingConnection_ im creating Thread, and then after Thread started, in Thread::run() socket is created. I've added code of _Thread::run()_ to question

Comment: I have a almost the [same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41671279/qsocketnotifier-socket-notifiers-cannot-be-enabled-or-disabled-from-another-thr) with you, could you help me have a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved issue. To do that i followed similar issue solution described here: [PROBLEM & SOLUTION](https://forum.qt.io/topic/62165/qsocketnotifier-socket-notifiers-cannot-be-enabled-or-disabled-from-another-thread/4)
I've resigned to use class MyThread, instead created class Worker and moved it to thread like here below:

```
void Test_Server::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor_)
{
    qDebug() << "void Test_Server::incomingConnection current thread: " << QThread::currentThread();
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor_ << "connecting...";
    Socket_map_.insert(number_,QByteArray::number(socketDescriptor_));
    QThread *thread_= new QThread;
    qDebug() << "void Test_Server::incomingConnection new thread_: " << thread_->thread();
    Test_Worker *worker = new Test_Worker(socketDescriptor_);
    worker->moveToThread(thread_);
    connect(thread_,SIGNAL(started()),worker,SLOT(create_socket_()));
    connect(this,SIGNAL(pass_socket_descriptor_(int)),worker,SLOT(set_socket_descriptor_(int)));
    connect(worker,SIGNAL(finished()),thread_,SLOT(quit()));
    connect(worker,SIGNAL(finished()),worker,SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(thread_,SIGNAL(finished()),thread_,SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(worker,SIGNAL(pass_data_to_server_(QByteArray,QByteArray)),this,SLOT(data_from_socket_(QByteArray,QByteArray)));
    connect(this,SIGNAL(pass_data_to_client_(QByteArray,QByteArray)),worker,SLOT(show_data_received_from_server_(QByteArray,QByteArray)));
    number_++;
    thread_->start();
}
```

> HINT: When i created socket via test_server signal create_socket_(int)
>   and socket create_socket(int), program didn't work correctly. To fix
>   that connect signal from starting thread to socket - create_socket_

Program now succesfuly without errors receive data from client 1 and pass it to client 2.

Answer (score 0):

`Test_Thread::write_data` is not running on the same thread where the socket was created, that is `Test_Thread::run()`. In the `QThread` class, only what runs on the `run` method runs on a separate thread.

Comment: If you comment `socket->waitForBytesWritten();` do you get the error ?

Comment: no, but without `socket->waitForBytesWritten();` sometimes server displays 2 separate data appended.